# Lightning-Web-Components Select Option prepopulate value

Tags: lightning-web-components

Let's say I have a Lightning-Web-Component with a select list with dynamic options where the value is a user Id and the label is the user's name:

```
<select class="slds-select" onchange={handleSelectChange} disabled={isDisabled} 
                         data-value={step.selectedUser} >
                                <option value="">--None--</option>
                                <template for:each={step.approvalTemplateStep.Approval_Step_Users__r} for:item="user">
                                    <option key={user.key} value={user.User__c}>
                                        {user.User__r.Name}</option>
                                </template>
                            </select>
```

How do I prepopulate the select option with a value? I have the value I want to be prepopulated in the variable called `step.selectedUser`.

Here's what I see on page load:
[image]

Here's what I should see:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can declare a 'hasDefault' getter in your controller and in your template, `if:true`, render a default result option:

```
    <template if:true={bears.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">

                <select class="slds-select" onchange={handleBearView} >

                         <!-- HERE Check for default value -->
                        <template if:true={hasDefaultResults}> 
                            <option value={hasDefaultResults.Id}>{hasDefaultResults.Name}</option>
                        </template>

                       <template  for:each={bears.data} for:item="bear">
                            <option key={bear.Id} value={bear.Id} >{bear.Name}</option>
                        </template>
                   </select> 
            </div>
    </template>
```

and create a getter:

```
get hasDefaultResults() {
        //check if array has data
        if(this.bears.data.length > 0){
              //here as an example, i set the second element from 
              //the array as the default, this can be whatever you want
            return (this.bears.data[1]);
        }
```

[image]

> Note: this will generate a duplicate value, so, you will have to
>   figure out a way to exclude it from your original array, either in
>   the template or in your controller.

Comment: Unfortunately, this select list in an iteration, so using a javascript var with a custom getter won't work since expressions cannot be passed into the function. I also really don't like the duplicative value. there must be a way to use javascript to manipulate the dom to set the selected attribute of the option which matches. I am still trying to figure this one out..

Comment: well, you can also create a design attribute, expose it, and there set a "value" as default, then in your array, if value matches anything in your array, re-order it and render