# How to update a select tag from the javascript in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Suppose I have a **select** tag like below and I want to update its value through any attribute in javascript, then how can I achieve it because document.getElementById will not work in the lightning Web Components

```
<select id="demoSel" name="demoSel">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you define an element with an ID attribute using LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256007/how-do-you-define-an-element-with-an-id-attribute-using-lwc)

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń I could not set the value using the **dataset** property aswell. I wanted to set the value of the element in js side only. Also not on the particular event of the target but on the any event.

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń I have to update the select tag in the connected call back which I was facing challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255907/lightning-web-components-select-option-prepopulate-value](https://LinkToAnswer)

the above link answered my question.
To be specific I had to use conditional rendering inside the **option** tag just like this:

```
 <option if:false={getSelectedOption}>
```

and use `getSelectedOption` as **getter** in which particular object of the array is returned which has to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

In order to access element in LWC you need to use

`this.template.querySelector();`

You cannot use ID in the above as the the IDs are generated dynamically when the component is rendered. But you can use other selectors namely the class and `data-*` attributes. For example if you add the `class = "selectclass"` to your select element, you can access it using

`this.template.querySelector(".selectclass");`

LWC reference for the above is at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work

Comment: can I use like this.template.querySelector(".selectclass").value = "somevalue" because I want to set the value through js side.

Comment: It should work or instead of value attribute, use selectedIndex attribute. I am not sure of the your usecase but instead of select, it might be better to use lightning-combobox component.

Comment: I have to update the select tag in the connected call back which I was facing challenge.